# Convergence/Divergence of Infinite Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}$$

What method would I use to test Convergence for this series? I've been staring at the problem for a while now, but since I only recently started learning series, I'm struggling with this problem.

All your given is this infinite series, and you're supposed to find if it converges or diverges using the application of theory we've learned (N-th term test, Geometric Series, Integral Test, DCT, LCT, Alternating Series Test, Ratio Test, and Root Test).

Comment: Would you find the problem easier without the $\sqrt n$?

Comment: Ok. And did you try any of these tests? What did you find? It's bizarre to list methods to solve a problem without actually using said methods. For instance, the LCT works here. So does the integral test, e.g.

Comment: This sum seems to be less than $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the comparison test. Note that for all $n\geq 1$,
$$\dfrac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\leq \dfrac{2n+n}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\leq 3\cdot\dfrac{n}{n^3+0}=\dfrac{3}{n^2}$$
Thus, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\leq 3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

To test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}$, we can try different tests to see which one applies.

First, we can use the limit comparison test. Let $a_n = \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{5/3}}$. Then,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^{2/3} + n^{-1/6}}{n^{8/3}} = 0.$$

Since this limit is finite and nonzero, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges (by the p-series test with $p=5/3>1$), then by the limit comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ also converges.

Alternatively, we can use the comparison test. Note that for $n\geq 1$,

$$0 < \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}} < \frac{3n}{n^3} = \frac{3}{n^2}.$$

Then, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{n^2}$ converges (by the p-series test with $p=2>1$), we can use the comparison test to conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}$ also converges.

Therefore, we can conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

To know if a series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ converges, you can try to check if it is convergent from a certain rank. i.e. does the series  the series $\sum_{n\geq N} a_n$ converges, for a certain $N\in\mathbb{N}$?

Note here, for $n$ big enough, we have
$$
    \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\sim\frac{2n}{n^3}.
$$
And by Riemann's series,  $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2}{n^2}<\infty\,.$ Therefore, $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}<\infty.$